# Letra depois de um número, como isto é chamado?

Tags: c#, .net

Como é o nome disso?

```
double  d1 = 0d;
decimal d2 = 0L;
float   d3 = 0f;
```

E onde posso encontrar uma referencia dos caracteres que posso utilizar? Se eu quiser fazer um *cast* de `0` para `short`, existe alguma letra para isto?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Como é o nome disso?

Não existe um nome próprio para isso, geralmente é referido como *sufixo* (*suffix*, *numeric suffix* ou ainda *type suffix*).

> E onde posso encontrar uma referencia dos caracteres que posso utilizar?

Você pode encontrar uma referência dos caracteres utilizados pelo C# [nesse link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bfft1t3c.aspx) (coluna *Type Suffix*). Basicamente são:

- `M` ou `m` para *decimal*.
- `D` ou `d` para *double*.
- `F` ou `f` para *float*.
- `L` ou `l` para *long*.
- `U` ou `u` para *uint*.
- `UL` ou `ul` para *ulong*.

É facultativo escrever na forma maiúscula ou minúscula, mas recomenda-se no caso do tipo *long* utilizar a forma maiúscula para não confundir com o caractere `1` (um).

> Se eu quiser fazer um cast de 0 para short, existe alguma letra para isto?

Não, a especificação do C# não dedica um sufixo para o tipo *short* (nem para *byte* e *char*).

---

Curiosidade: para o tipo *ulong*, além de `UL` e `ul`, pode se utilizar qualquer variação com as letras *L* e *U*: `Ul`, `uL`, `lu`, `LU`, `Lu`, `lU`.